# Are sessions safe to use to store permission information

Tags: django, session

I am currently writing an application in Django and I am looking at storing specific permission information during a user's session. The permissions are made up of the following values:

- No Permissions - 0
- Read Only - 1
- Edit - 2
- Add and Edit - 3
- Full Permission - 4

The higher the value, the better the permission a user has. If a user has only "Edit" permission for the module "Projects", I want to store that somewhere so I don't have to get Django to query the database constantly. Would it be appropriate to use the following;

```
request.session['project_permission'] = '2'
```

Or would the user be able to edit this value and sneak in a higher number like 3 or 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Django's default sessions model backend, the user will not be able to edit any session related data.

The only information that is stored on the client side is the sessionid (in a cookie) which is the primary key to the Django Sessions table.

Django sessions table also has a column called "session_data" which stores the hashed session data (which the user will not have access to, unless they have access to your db)

I do not recommend storing permissions in sessions, there are better ways to implement this.
Additionally, sessions (default django sessions model backend) data is stored in the database, so indirectly queries are being made

Comment: Thank you - I will go back to the drawing board and make it query based, unless you have any other better ways.

Comment: Would be able to recommend solutions if you can share your data models. And would a user have different permissions on different projects? or is it something like user "X"  has "Read Only" so he can only read all projects

Comment: https://github.com/robotichead/NearBeach/blob/master/models.py is the model file. Essentially a user is connected to a group AND a permission set. They can be assigned as many groups/permission sets possible. The permission set defines what that user will have access to, i.e. projects. So yes a user could have different permissions depending on both the groups they are allocated to and their permission sets within. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Your data models are huge, it might take me quite a lot of time to understand them. Anyway good luck with your project